How does joint torque varies wrt joint velocities in Recursive Newton Euler algorithm?
I'm currently working on solving the inverse dynamics of a 6-axis articulated robot, similar to the UR5, using the recursive Newton-Euler algorithm. I'm very confused with the results I'm getting, as the magnitudes of the torques differ when I input the same angle with different directions.
Consider a UR5 robot in its initial position, standing upright. I'm using joint 2 velocity and acceleration of +1 and positioning joint 2 at +90 degrees. Through the RNEA, I get a certain torque value, lets say a. However, when I put joint 2 at -90 degrees without altering any other parameters, I get a different torque value, lets say b, where b is not equal to a.
But, when I set joint 2 at -90 degrees and invert the joint velocities and accelerations to -1, I get a torque value for joint 2, whose magnitude is equal to the magnitude of a.
I am confused by this, and not sure what this means. I expected the magnitudes of the torques to remain consistent, even when the joint velocities and accelerations were unchanged, for a certain joint position.
Can someone explain what this result means, and  give any insights on how to interpret the torques generated through RNEA ?
